# Adding an alias for Zsh

Tags: command-line, alias, zsh, heroku

To scale my heroku workers up and down I wanted to add an alias for them because of the frequency with which these commands are used. However when I tried to add the alias it did not work.

For example: `alias scale_down= heroku ps:scale worker1=0 worker2=0 -r remote_name`

I believe because of the presence of multiple `=`s in my command, it is not generating a single alias for the entire command but making aliases out of the worker names, which don't work because `worker_1=0` in itself makes no sense.

I have tried adding it with quotes and tried adding it to the source file, but to no avail. The command executes, but nothing is triggered, i.e. the workers are not scaled up or down.

How may I add this alias?

Comment: `alias scale_down='heroku ps:scale worker1=0 worker2=0 -r remote_name'` should work.

Comment: @muru, it executes successfully, but there is the command is no effect, for example I ran the scale_down command in a directory where the remote does not exist and it should hence throw an error. It executed successfully without any error message

Comment: Try removing the space between `scale_down=` and `heroku ps`

Comment: That's a different problem - as long as the alias works, you should be investigating heroku. I don't know what heroku is or why it should throw an error. Test the alias you created using `alias scale_down`.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju thanks! that works, can you submit that as an answer? I'll accept it :)

Comment: @muru: my fault, I had an extra space which caused the error. thanks for taking a look! :)

Comment: What? My suggestion in the first comment does not have that alias. Did you even try it before responding?

Comment: @muru: it was a mistake in my understanding of your comment.  I tried the alias with quotes but in the same command that I mentioned in the question. I did not notice the removal of space around `=` and the rest of the command.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the space and lack of quotes. sh-like shells are serious about spaces.

```
alias scale_down= heroku ps:scale worker1=0 worker2=0 -r remote_name
```

should be changed to

```
alias scale_down='heroku ps:scale worker1=0 worker2=0 -r remote_name'
```

Note no space around `=`, and quotes